# PySpark Hive queries aren't showing output

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am able to create, drop, modify tables using pyspark and hivecontext. I load a list with commands I want to send, in string format, and pass them into this function:

```
def hiveCommands(commands, database):
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(database + 'project').setMaster('local')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    df = HiveContext(sc)
    f = df.sql('use ' + database)
    for command in commands:
        f = df.sql(command)
        f.collect()
```

It works fine for maintenance, but I'm trying to dip my toes into analysis, and I don't see any output when I try to send a command like "describe table."

I just that it takes in the command and executes it without any errors, but I don't see what the actual output of the query is. I may need to mess with my .profile or .bashrc, not really sure. Something of a Linux newby. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do expect any output? There is no single method here that can produce it.

Comment: Well I tried "print f" at the end of my loop and it didn't produce anything, so I thought maybe there is a special method that is needed.

Comment: I would suggest going back to the docs an checking what exactly `SQLContext.sql` is doing. There is nothing useful to print there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `show` method to see results:

```
for command in commands:
    df.sql(command).show()
```